# Characteristics of GNSS BLE Profile

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need your help. I am trying to send GNSS informations via a BLE Server and read them with my Client.

Is there already a service with characteristics to send GNSS data or do I have to write it myself?
I found on the Bluetooth home page an profile for GNSS: https://www.bluetooth.com/de/specifications/specs/global-navigation-satellite-system-profile-1/

However, I can't figure out what characteristics this uses. In other profile spezifications these are clearly mentioned. Maybe you can help me, if I'm just missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: That profile is built on Bluetooth classic and not BLE. Are you writing both the client and the server?

Comment: @ukBaz yes i'm writing both

Comment: You are free to do what ever makes sense for your situation. Reading the `GATT Specification Supplement` at https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/ should give you some ideas. There is guidance on choosing UUID at: https://novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/

Comment: @ukBaz Thanks for your help! So there is no "official" Profile for Sendling GNSS Data with Bluetooth Low Energy, right?

Comment: There is [Location and Navigation Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) (LNS) and [Indoor Positioning Service](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/) (IPS). LNS exposes location and navigation-related data from a Location and Navigation sensor intended for outdoor activity applications. In the GSS document it has `3.128 Location and Speed`, I don't know if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GNSS BLE Profile. The Profile in the link is for classic bluetooth.
I wrote my own GNSS Profile!
Thanks for your help.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).